# Como agregar una scrollbarr a una lista

Tags: css, scroll, menu

quisiera preguntarles que podría agregar en el CSS con bootstrap para tener una barra scroll a esta lista... y visualizar mejor su contenido...
Gracias

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 2):

aqui te dejo un ejemplo, si quires personalizar mas tu select te recomiendo usar bootstrap-select, es bastante personalizable. Aqui te dejo la documentacion por si te interesa: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <select class="form-select" multiple aria-label="multiple select example" size="3">
        <option selected disabled>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Three</option>
        <option value="5">Three</option>
      </select>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tengo esa libreria... pero aun no encuentro la parte del scroll o que tendria que hacer

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta, ahora si funciona el scrollbar, tienes que jugar con la propiedad size para indicar cuantas opciones quieres que se muestren.